SL and TP not triggered by strategy,exit function
My strategy script open trades properly but does not exit from the trades: the SL or TP is not triggered. Very awkward - this behavior happens only when I change one of the entry conditions (meaning "conf_type" from "Body" to "Wick").
But this condition is independent from the calculation of SL / TP prices or any other entry conditions. Also, no other strategy.cancel_all and strategy.close_all functions are not taken into consideration by the strategy script in order to exit from the trades. Could someone help me please to figure it out?
These are the relevant block from the code:
//@version=5
strategy("DR/IDR GoldFish Tester", 
     overlay=true, 
     max_lines_count = 500, max_boxes_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)
import TradingView/Strategy/3
import PineCoders/VisibleChart/4 as PCchart
import ID/Futures_Contracts_Valability/1 as Valability

TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York'

var GRP1 = 'ADR Time Settings'
i_ADR_Time                  = input.session('1930-2030', 'DR',                  group = GRP1)
i_ADR_Extend                = input.session('2030-0200', 'DR Lines',            group = GRP1)
i_ADR_Confirmation_Time     = input.session('2030-2100', '❗ Confirmation',      group = GRP1)
i_ADR_Entry_Time            = input.session('2100-0130', 'Setups',              group = GRP1)

var GRP2 = 'ODR Time Settings'
i_ODR_Time                  = input.session('0300-0400', 'DR',                  group = GRP2)
i_ODR_Extend                = input.session('0400-0830', 'DR Lines',            group = GRP2)
i_ODR_Confirmation_Time     = input.session('0400-0430', '❗ Confirmation',      group = GRP2)
i_ODR_Entry_Time            = input.session('0430-0800', 'Setups',              group = GRP2)

var GRP3 = 'RDR Time Settings'
i_RDR_Time                  = input.session('0930-1030', 'DR',                  group = GRP3)
i_RDR_Extend                = input.session('1030-1600', 'DR Lines',            group = GRP3)
i_RDR_Confirmation_Time     = input.session('1030-1100', '❗ Confirmation',      group = GRP3)
i_RDR_Entry_Time            = input.session('1100-1530', 'Setups',              group = GRP3)

var GRP4 = 'Strategy Parameters'
i_Entry_Monday              = input.bool(true,              'Monday',       inline = 'entry_day', group = GRP4)
i_Entry_Tuesday             = input.bool(true,              'Tuesday',      inline = 'entry_day', group = GRP4)
i_Entry_Wednesday           = input.bool(true,              'Wednesday',    inline = 'entry_day', group = GRP4)
i_Entry_Thursday            = input.bool(true,              'Thursday',     inline = 'entry_day', group = GRP4)
i_Entry_Friday              = input.bool(true,              'Friday',       inline = 'entry_day', group = GRP4)
i_Session                   = input.string('RDR',           'Choose Session',           options = ['ADR', 'ODR', 'RDR'],                group = GRP4)
i_conf_Type                 = input.string('Body',          'Confirmation type',        options = ['Body', 'Wick'],                     group = GRP4)
i_ReturnM7Box_Type          = input.string('Body',          'Return into M7Box type',   options = ['Body', 'Wick'],                     group = GRP4)
i_Allow_Distance            = input.bool(true,              'Allow distance',                                                           group = GRP4) 
i_M7Box_SD_Bool             = input.bool(true,              'Minim M7Box Size SD       ',                  inline = 'M7Box_SD',         group = GRP4)
i_M7Box_SD                  = input.float(0.2,              '',                             step = 0.05, inline = 'M7Box_SD',           group = GRP4)
i_SL_Type                   = input.string('O/C',           'Stop Loss type             ',   options = ['O/C', 'M7Box'],                group = GRP4, tooltip = 'O/C - Open/Close Line \nM7Box - Standard Deviation level inside M7Box')
i_SL_SD                     = input.float(-0.1,             'Stop Loss SD M7Box           ', step = 0.05,                               group = GRP4, tooltip = 'Not taken into consideration if O/C SL type is selected')
i_SL_Ticks                  = input.int(3,                  'Offset SL (ticks)          ',   step = 1,                                  group = GRP4, tooltip = 'Additional ticks to SL')
i_TP_SD                     = input.float(1.5,              'Take Profit SD               ', step = 0.1,                                group = GRP4)
i_Max_Loss_Trades           = input.int(2,                  'Max losses per Session     ',  minval = 1, maxval = 10,                    group = GRP4)
i_Move_SL_to_BE             = input.bool(true,              'Move SL to BE. ',              inline = 'SL to BE',                        group = GRP4)
i_RR_to_BE                  = input.float(2,                'Minim RR   ', step = 0.1,      inline = 'SL to BE',                        group = GRP4)
i_Show_BE                   = input.bool(true,              'Show BE target',               inline = 'SL to BE',                        group = GRP4)
i_SL_BE_Time_Bool           = input.bool(false,             'Move SL to BE after        ',  inline = 'SL to BE Time',                   group = GRP4)
i_SL_BE_Time                = input.session('1530-1600',    '',                             inline = 'SL to BE Time',                   group = GRP4)
i_Anand_Entry               = input.bool(true,              'Anand Entry.',                 inline = 'Anand',                           group = GRP4)
i_minRR                     = input.float(3,                'Minim RR      ', step = 0.1,    inline = 'Anand',                          group = GRP4)
i_M7Box_Direction           = input.bool(false,             'Enter trades in the direction of M7Box',                                   group = GRP4)
i_ADR_Mid                   = input.bool(false,             'Enter trades in the direction of ADR Mid',                                 group = GRP4)
i_ClosePosition_EOS         = input.bool(true,              'Close positions at the End of Session',                                    group = GRP4)
i_ADR_Close_Time            = input.session('2030-0155',    'ADR Close Time',                                                           group = GRP4)
i_ODR_Close_Time            = input.session('0400-0825',    'ODR Close Time',                                                           group = GRP4)
i_RDR_Close_Time            = input.session('1030-1555',    'RDR Close Time',                                                           group = GRP4)
i_Cancel_LO                 = input.bool(true,              'Cancel Anand LO after     ',   inline = 'cancel order',                    group = GRP4)
i_Cancel_LO_Time            = input.session('1535-1540',    '',                             inline = 'cancel order',                    group = GRP4)
// i_false_Day                 = input.bool(false,             'Entry after False Day confirmed',                                          group = GRP4)

var GRP6 = 'Position Size'
i_Risk_Per_Trade        = input.float(1.0,              'Position Size                   ', step = 1,           inline = 'Position Size', group = GRP6)
i_PositionSize_Type     = input.string('% of Equity',   '', options = ['Contracts', '% of Equity', 'Default'], inline = 'Position Size',  group = GRP6)
i_Position_Limits       = input.int(6,                  'Position Limit (Contracts)',                                                     group = GRP6)
i_Compounding           = input.bool(false,             'Compounding efect',                                                              group = GRP6)

// Indicator Variables
var int     startTime           = na
var int     endTime             = na
var string  currentSession      = na
var int     bodyConfUp          = na
var int     wickConfUp          = na
var int     bodyConfDown        = na
var int     wickConfDown        = na
var line    DR_Low_Line         = na
var line    DR_High_Line        = na
var line    IDR_Low_Line        = na
var line    IDR_High_Line       = na
var line    IDR_Mid_Line        = na
var line    Open_Line           = na
var line    Close_Line          = na
var box     DR_Box              = na
var float   DR_Low              = na
var float   DR_High             = na
var float   IDR_Mid             = na
var float   IDR_Low             = na
var float   IDR_High            = na
var float   Session_Open        = na
var float   Session_Close       = na

// Strategy Variables
bool        entry_Monday            = na
bool        entry_Tuesday           = na
bool        entry_Wednesday         = na
bool        entry_Thursday          = na
bool        entry_Friday            = na
var bool    Conf_Time_LB_Pers       = na
var bool    Conf_Time_SB_Pers       = na
var bool    Conf_Time_LW_Pers       = na
var bool    Conf_Time_SW_Pers       = na
var bool    TP_Not_Reached_Long     = na
var bool    TP_Not_Reached_Short    = na
var bool    false_Day               = na
var bool    after_Entry_bool        = na
var bool    Anand_Label             = na
var float   Initial_SL_Price        = na
var float   SL_Price                = na
var float   TP_Price                = na
var float   Swing_High              = na
var float   Swing_Low               = na
var float   Anand_EntryPrice        = na
var float   DR_Price1               = na
var float   DR_Price2               = na
var float   Entry_Price             = na
var int     bar_index_last          = na
var int     bar_index_LB            = na
var int     bar_index_SB            = na
var int     bar_index_LW            = na
var int     bar_index_SW            = na
var int     Entry_Time_Hour_Int     = na
var int     Entry_Time_Min_Int      = na
var int     bar_index_TP_Reached    = na
var int     after_Confirmation      = na
var int     Session_Loss_Trades     = na
var int     after_Entry             = na
var int     Anand_Entry_Time        = na
var bool    Return_M7Box            = na
var bool    Return_Wick             = na
var bool    Return_Body             = na
var float   ADR_Mid_Price           = na
var line    ADR_Mid_Line            = na
var int     BLtime                  = na
var int     WLtime                  = na
var int     BStime                  = na
var int     WStime                  = na
 
// Indicator Calculations {
 
// Use the 5 minute timeframe if the chart timeframe is lower than 5m 
[m5_open, m5_high, m5_low, m5_close] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', [open, high, low, close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

DR_Time = (i_Show_RDR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_RDR_Time, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_ODR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ODR_Time, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_ADR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ADR_Time, TIMEZONE))) 
DR_Extend = (i_Show_RDR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_RDR_Extend, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_ODR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ODR_Extend, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_ADR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ADR_Extend, TIMEZONE))) 
Confirmation_Time = switch (i_Session)
    'ADR' => i_ADR_Confirmation_Time
    'ODR' => i_ODR_Confirmation_Time
    'RDR' => i_RDR_Confirmation_Time

if timeframe.isintraday
    // Initiate DR Levels
    if DR_Time and not DR_Time[1]
        DR_High       := m5_high
        DR_Low        := m5_low
        IDR_High      := m5_close
        IDR_Low       := m5_close
        Session_Open  := m5_open        
        DR_High_Line  := line.new(bar_index, DR_High, bar_index + 1, DR_High, color = i_DR_LineColor, style = i_DR_LineStyle)
        DR_Low_Line   := line.new(bar_index, DR_Low, bar_index + 1, DR_Low, color = i_DR_LineColor, style = i_DR_LineStyle)
        IDR_High_Line := line.new(bar_index, IDR_High, bar_index + 1, IDR_High, color = i_IDR_LineColor, style = i_IDR_LineStyle)
        IDR_Low_Line  := line.new(bar_index, IDR_Low, bar_index + 1, IDR_Low, color = i_IDR_LineColor, style = i_IDR_LineStyle)
        Open_Line     := i_Show_Open_Line ? line.new(bar_index, Session_Open, bar_index + 1, Session_Open, color = i_Open_LineColor, style = i_Open_LineStyle) : na
        DR_Box        := box.new(bar_index, IDR_Low, bar_index + 1, IDR_High, border_color = na, bgcolor = Session_Open < m5_close ? i_UpBoxColor : Session_Open > m5_close ? i_DownBoxColor : color.new(color.gray, 70))

    // Manage DR Levels
    if not na(DR_High_Line)
        if DR_Time or DR_Extend
            line.set_x2(DR_High_Line, bar_index)
            line.set_x2(DR_Low_Line, bar_index)
            line.set_x2(IDR_High_Line, bar_index)
            line.set_x2(IDR_Low_Line, bar_index)
            if not na(Open_Line)
                line.set_x2(Open_Line, bar_index)

        if DR_Time
            box.set_right(DR_Box, bar_index)
            if m5_high > line.get_y1(DR_High_Line)
                line.set_y1(DR_High_Line, m5_high)
                line.set_y2(DR_High_Line, m5_high)
            if m5_low < line.get_y1(DR_Low_Line)
                line.set_y1(DR_Low_Line, m5_low)
                line.set_y2(DR_Low_Line, m5_low)
            if m5_close > line.get_y1(IDR_High_Line)
                box.set_top(DR_Box, m5_close)
                line.set_y1(IDR_High_Line, m5_close)
                line.set_y2(IDR_High_Line, m5_close)
            if m5_close < line.get_y1(IDR_Low_Line)
                box.set_bottom(DR_Box, m5_close)
                line.set_y1(IDR_Low_Line, m5_close)
                line.set_y2(IDR_Low_Line, m5_close)
            if Session_Open < m5_close
                box.set_bgcolor(DR_Box, i_UpBoxColor)
            if Session_Open > m5_close
                box.set_bgcolor(DR_Box, i_DownBoxColor)


            bodyConfUp := 0, wickConfUp := 0, bodyConfDown := 0, wickConfDown := 0, 
            bar_index_last := na
            Conf_Time_LB_Pers := false, Conf_Time_SB_Pers := false, Conf_Time_LW_Pers := false, Conf_Time_SW_Pers := false 
            bar_index_LB := 0,bar_index_LW := 0, bar_index_SB := 0, bar_index_SW := 0
            false_Day := false
            TP_Not_Reached_Long := false, TP_Not_Reached_Short := false
            Anand_EntryPrice := na, 
            after_Confirmation := 0, Swing_High := na, Swing_Low := na, 
            Entry_Price := na
            DR_Price1 := na, DR_Price2 := na
            Session_Loss_Trades := 0
            after_Entry := 0, after_Entry_bool := false, Anand_Label := false
            SL_Price := na, Initial_SL_Price := na
            Anand_Entry_Time := na
            Return_Wick := na, Return_Body := na, Return_M7Box := na
            BLtime := na, WLtime := na, BStime := na, WStime := na
        
        if DR_Extend and not DR_Extend[1]
            DR_High       := line.get_y1(DR_High_Line)
            DR_Low        := line.get_y1(DR_Low_Line)
            IDR_High      := line.get_y1(IDR_High_Line)
            IDR_Low       := line.get_y1(IDR_Low_Line)
            IDR_Mid       := math.avg(IDR_High, IDR_Low)
            Session_Close := m5_close[1]
            IDR_Mid_Line  := i_Show_Mid_Line ? line.new(bar_index, IDR_Mid, bar_index + 1, IDR_Mid, color = i_IDR_Mid_LineColor, style = i_IDR_Mid_LineStyle) : na
            ADR_Mid_Line  := i_Show_ADR_Mid and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ADR_Extend, TIMEZONE)) ? line.new(time, IDR_Mid, time + ADR_Mid_Line_Time_Extend, IDR_Mid, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = i_ADR_Mid_LineColor, style = i_ADR_Mid_LineStyle) : na
            Close_Line    := i_Show_Close_Line ? line.new(bar_index - 1, Session_Close, bar_index, Session_Close, color = i_Close_LineColor, style = i_Close_LineStyle) : na

        if DR_Extend
            line.set_x2(IDR_Mid_Line, bar_index)
            // line.set_x2(ADR_Mid_Line, bar_index)
            if not na(Close_Line)
                line.set_x2(Close_Line, bar_index)

    // Body Confirmation Long
    if close > DR_High and DR_Extend
        bodyConfUp := bodyConfUp + 1
        if bodyConfUp == 1
            if not na(time(timeframe.period, Confirmation_Time, TIMEZONE)) 
                Conf_Time_LB_Pers := true
            bar_index_LB := bar_index
            label.new(bar_index, na, "", xloc.bar_index, yloc.abovebar, color.green, label.style_triangleup, na, size.auto, tooltip = str.format_time(time, 'HH:mm', TIMEZONE))
            BLtime := time

    // Wick Confirmation Long 
    if high > DR_High and close <= DR_High and DR_Extend and bodyConfUp == 0
        wickConfUp := wickConfUp + 1
        if wickConfUp == 1
            if not na(time(timeframe.period, Confirmation_Time, TIMEZONE))
                Conf_Time_LW_Pers := true
            bar_index_LW := bar_index
            label.new(bar_index, na, "", xloc.bar_index, yloc.abovebar, color.green, label.style_circle, na, size.auto, tooltip = str.format_time(time, 'HH:mm', TIMEZONE))
            WLtime := time

    // Body Confirmation Short
    if close < DR_Low and DR_Extend 
        bodyConfDown := bodyConfDown + 1
        if bodyConfDown == 1
            if not na(time(timeframe.period, Confirmation_Time, TIMEZONE))
                Conf_Time_SB_Pers := true
            bar_index_SB := bar_index
            label.new(bar_index, na, "", xloc.bar_index, yloc.belowbar, color.red, label.style_triangledown, na, size.auto, tooltip = str.format_time(time, 'HH:mm', TIMEZONE))
            BStime := time

    // Wick Confirmation Short
    if low < DR_Low and close >= DR_Low and DR_Extend and bodyConfDown == 0
        wickConfDown := wickConfDown + 1
        if wickConfDown == 1
            if not na(time(timeframe.period, Confirmation_Time, TIMEZONE))
                Conf_Time_SW_Pers := true
            bar_index_SW := bar_index
            label.new(bar_index, na, "", xloc.bar_index, yloc.belowbar, color.red, label.style_circle, na, size.auto, tooltip = str.format_time(time, 'HH:mm', TIMEZONE))
            WStime := time

// STRATEGY Calculations {

// Entry Day {
entry_Day = i_Entry_Monday and dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday ? true :
     i_Entry_Tuesday and dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.tuesday ? true :
     i_Entry_Wednesday and dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.wednesday ? true :
     i_Entry_Thursday and dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.thursday ? true : 
     i_Entry_Friday and dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.friday ? true :
     false
// }

// Confirmation Direction {
conf_Direction = bodyConfUp != 0    and bodyConfDown == 0 ?                                     'Long' :
     bodyConfDown != 0              and bodyConfUp == 0 ?                                       'Short' :
     wickConfUp != 0                and bodyConfDown == 0   and bodyConfUp == 0 ?               'Long' :
     wickConfDown != 0              and bodyConfUp == 0     and bodyConfDown == 0 ?             'Short' :
     bodyConfUp != 0                and bodyConfDown != 0   and bar_index_LB < bar_index_SB ?   'Long' :
     bodyConfUp != 0                and bodyConfDown != 0   and bar_index_LB > bar_index_SB ?   'Short' :
     na
// }

// Confirmation Type {
bar_index_last := bar_index_LB == 0 and bar_index_LW == 0 and bar_index_SB == 0 and bar_index_SW == 0 ? na : math.max(bar_index_LB, bar_index_LW, bar_index_SB, bar_index_SW)
conf_Type = bodyConfUp != 0 and bodyConfDown == 0 ?                                         'Body' :
     bodyConfDown != 0      and bodyConfUp == 0 ?                                           'Body' :
     wickConfUp != 0        and bodyConfDown == 0   and bodyConfUp == 0 ?                   'Wick' :
     wickConfDown != 0      and bodyConfUp == 0     and bodyConfDown == 0 ?                 'Wick' :
     bodyConfUp != 0        and bodyConfDown != 0   and bar_index_LB < bar_index_SB ?       'Body' :
     bodyConfUp != 0        and bodyConfDown != 0   and bar_index_LB > bar_index_SB ?       'Body' :
     na
// }

// Confirmation Time {
conf_Time = conf_Direction    == 'Long'   and i_conf_Type == 'Body' ? Conf_Time_LB_Pers :
     conf_Direction           == 'Long'   and i_conf_Type == 'Wick' ? Conf_Time_LW_Pers :
     conf_Direction           == 'Short'  and i_conf_Type == 'Body' ? Conf_Time_SB_Pers :
     conf_Direction           == 'Short'  and i_conf_Type == 'Wick' ? Conf_Time_SW_Pers :
     na
// }

// Swing_High and Swing_Low {
if DR_Extend and i_conf_Type == conf_Type
    after_Confirmation := after_Confirmation + 1
Swing_High  := after_Confirmation == 2 ? high : after_Confirmation > 2 and high > Swing_High ? high : Swing_High
Swing_Low   := after_Confirmation == 2 ? low : after_Confirmation > 2 and low < Swing_Low ? low : Swing_Low
// }

// M7Box Dimension {
bool M7Box_SD = na
if i_M7Box_SD_Bool
    if math.round(math.abs(Session_Open - Session_Close) / math.abs(IDR_High - IDR_Low), 2) >= i_M7Box_SD 
        M7Box_SD := true
    else
        M7Box_SD := false
else 
    M7Box_SD := true
// }
    
// SL Price + Conditions {
Initial_SL_Price := switch i_SL_Type
    'O/C'   => conf_Direction == 'Long' ? math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) - syminfo.mintick * i_SL_Ticks : math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) + syminfo.mintick * i_SL_Ticks
    'M7Box' => conf_Direction == 'Long' ? math.round_to_mintick(math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) + math.abs(Session_Open - Session_Close) * i_SL_SD - syminfo.mintick * i_SL_Ticks) : math.round_to_mintick(math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) - math.abs(Session_Open - Session_Close) * i_SL_SD + syminfo.mintick * i_SL_Ticks)
bool SL_Not_Beyond = conf_Direction == 'Long' and close > Initial_SL_Price ? true : conf_Direction == 'Short' and close < Initial_SL_Price ? true : false
// }

// TP Price + Conditions {
TP_Price := conf_Direction == 'Long' ? math.round_to_mintick(IDR_High + math.abs(IDR_High - IDR_Low) * i_TP_SD) : math.round_to_mintick(IDR_Low - math.abs(IDR_High - IDR_Low) * i_TP_SD)
bool TP_Not_Reached = conf_Direction == 'Long' and Swing_High < TP_Price ? true : conf_Direction == 'Short' and Swing_Low > TP_Price ? true : false
// }

// Anand Entry {
Anand_EntryPrice := math.round_to_mintick((TP_Price + Initial_SL_Price * i_minRR) / (i_minRR + 1))
bool Anand_Entry = i_Anand_Entry and conf_Direction == 'Long' and close > Anand_EntryPrice ? true and close > math.abs(Session_Open - Session_Close): i_Anand_Entry and conf_Direction == 'Short' and close < Anand_EntryPrice and close < math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) ? true : false 
// }

// Entry Time {
bool Entry_Time = (i_Show_ADR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ADR_Entry_Time, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_ODR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ODR_Entry_Time, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_RDR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_RDR_Entry_Time, TIMEZONE)))
// }

// Return in M7Box {
if i_conf_Type == conf_Type and DR_Extend and after_Confirmation > 1
    if conf_Direction == 'Long'
        Return_Wick := low < math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) and math.min(open, close) >= math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) ? true : Return_Wick
        Return_Body := math.min(open, close) < math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) ? true : Return_Body
    if conf_Direction == 'Short'
        Return_Wick := high > math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) and math.max(open, close) <= math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) ? true : Return_Wick
        Return_Body := math.max(open, close) > math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) ? true : Return_Body
    if i_ReturnM7Box_Type == 'Wick' 
        if Return_Wick and na(Return_Body)
            Return_M7Box := true
        if Return_Body
            Return_M7Box := false
    if i_ReturnM7Box_Type == 'Body' and Return_Body
        Return_M7Box := true
else 
    Return_M7Box := false
// }

// Body Close outside M7Box {
bool Body_Closes = na
if i_Allow_Distance
    if Return_M7Box[2] and Return_M7Box[1] and Return_M7Box and strategy.closedtrades[2] == strategy.closedtrades[1] 
        if conf_Direction == 'Long' 
            if close[2] > math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close[1] < math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close > math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) 
                Body_Closes := true
        if conf_Direction == 'Short'
            if close[2] < math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close[1] > math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close < math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close)
                Body_Closes := true
    if Return_M7Box[1] and Return_M7Box
        if conf_Direction == 'Long'
            if close[1] > math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close > math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close)
                Body_Closes := true
        if conf_Direction == 'Short'
            if close[1] < math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close < math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close)
                Body_Closes := true
else
    if Return_M7Box[1] and Return_M7Box
        if conf_Direction == 'Long'
            if close[1] > math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close > math.max(Session_Open, Session_Close)
                Body_Closes := true
        if conf_Direction == 'Short'
            if close[1] < math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close) and close < math.min(Session_Open, Session_Close)
                Body_Closes := true
// }

// M7Box Color {
bool M7Box_Direction = na
if i_M7Box_Direction 
    if conf_Direction == 'Long' and Session_Open < Session_Close
        M7Box_Direction := true
    else if conf_Direction == 'Short' and Session_Open > Session_Close
        M7Box_Direction := true
else
    M7Box_Direction := true
// }

// Position Size {
float quantity = switch(i_PositionSize_Type)
    'Contracts' => i_Risk_Per_Trade
    => Anand_Entry ? i_Compounding ? math.round((strategy.equity * i_Risk_Per_Trade * 0.01) / (math.abs(Anand_EntryPrice - Initial_SL_Price) * syminfo.pointvalue)) : math.round((strategy.initial_capital * i_Risk_Per_Trade * 0.01) / (math.abs(Anand_EntryPrice - Initial_SL_Price) * syminfo.pointvalue)) : i_Compounding ? math.round((strategy.equity * i_Risk_Per_Trade * 0.01) / (math.abs(close - Initial_SL_Price) * syminfo.pointvalue)) : math.round((strategy.initial_capital * i_Risk_Per_Trade * 0.01) / (math.abs(close - Initial_SL_Price) * syminfo.pointvalue))
// Position Size }

strategy.risk.max_position_size(i_Position_Limits)

// Entry Conditions {
bool Entry_Conditions = DR_Extend and entry_Day and Entry_Time and (conf_Direction == 'Long' or conf_Direction == 'Short') and not false_Day and i_conf_Type == conf_Type and conf_Time and SL_Not_Beyond and TP_Not_Reached and Session_Loss_Trades < i_Max_Loss_Trades and Return_M7Box and Body_Closes and M7Box_SD and M7Box_Direction and strategy.position_size == 0 and strategy.closedtrades == strategy.closedtrades[1] and Ctr_Valab_Filter
if Entry_Conditions
    if Anand_Entry
        strategy.entry(conf_Direction == 'Long' ? 'Long' : 'Short', conf_Direction == 'Long' ? strategy.long : strategy.short, qty = quantity, limit = Anand_EntryPrice)
        after_Entry_bool := true, Anand_Label := true
        Anand_Entry_Time := time + 300000
    else
        strategy.entry(conf_Direction == 'Long' ? 'Long' : 'Short', conf_Direction == 'Long' ? strategy.long : strategy.short, qty = quantity)
// }


// Moving SL to BE {
if i_Move_SL_to_BE and strategy.position_size[1] != 0  and barstate.isconfirmed
    if strategy.position_size > 0 and high >= strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1) + i_RR_to_BE * math.abs(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1) - Initial_SL_Price)
        SL_Price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
    else if strategy.position_size < 0 and low <= strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1) - i_RR_to_BE * math.abs(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1) - Initial_SL_Price)
        SL_Price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
else 
    SL_Price := Initial_SL_Price

if i_SL_BE_Time_Bool 
    if (i_Show_ADR or i_Show_ODR or i_Show_RDR) and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_SL_BE_Time, TIMEZONE)) and ((strategy.position_size > 0 and close > strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)) or (strategy.position_size < 0 and close < strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)))
        SL_Price := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
// }

strategy.exit('Exit', strategy.position_size > 0 ? 'Long' : 'Short', limit = TP_Price, stop = SL_Price)

// Counting Loss Trades per current session {
if strategy.losstrades > strategy.losstrades[1]
    Session_Loss_Trades += 1
// }

// Reset SL level if entering in a new trade after SL movel to BE in previous trade {
if strategy.closedtrades != strategy.closedtrades[1]
    SL_Price := Initial_SL_Price
// }

// Cancel Anand Entry Order after expiring Duration {
if not na(time(timeframe.period, i_Cancel_LO_Time, TIMEZONE))
    strategy.cancel_all()
// }

// Cancel Limit Orders + Close Trades and the End of Session {
bool Open_Trade_Time = (i_Show_ADR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ADR_Close_Time, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_ODR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_ODR_Close_Time, TIMEZONE))) or (i_Show_RDR and not na(time(timeframe.period, i_RDR_Close_Time, TIMEZONE)))
if not Open_Trade_Time and i_ClosePosition_EOS  
    strategy.close_all('Exit at End_Of_Sess')
if not Open_Trade_Time[1]
    strategy.cancel_all()
if not TP_Not_Reached
    strategy.cancel_all()
if conf_Type != i_conf_Type
    strategy.cancel_all()
// }

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/hhjNS.png)

I have read all the questions posted here referring to strategy.exit function in relation with SL and TP limit orders but did not find a solution to my problem. 


Please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example. My money is on strategy.cancel_all() calls.

Edited the post and added all the relevant blocks from the script. Hope to offer a more clearer picture.

If you are familiar with DR/IDR strategy, the code is more simpler to understand. As far as I noticed until now, the only trades where the script does not trigger SL / TP are the ones where a Body confirmation occurs after the Wick confirmation. Where there is a session with a Wick confirmation only for the rest of the session, there are no issues, the script runs correctly and SL or TP are triggered. Also, when Body Confirmation is selected as input, there are no problems.

@vitruvius Mate you are a genius. Yes, if the confirmation changes after opening a trade, the limit orders (SL/TP) are canceled. So I added another simple condition (strategy.position_size == 0) to assure that there are no open trades, in order to cancel the limit orders if the confirmation_type is changed... Thank you a lot once again for your hint !!!!

strategy.cancel_all() will cancel strategy.exit() orders as well.

strategy.cancel_all() → void
A command to cancel/deactivate all pending orders generated by any of
the following functions: strategy.order, strategy.entry,
strategy.exit, and strategy.close.

So, you need to ensure that you are only calling that function when you really want to cancel all pending orders.
Alternatively, you can specify an order id if you want to be specifc and use strategy.cancel() instead.

strategy.cancel(id) → void
It is a command to cancel/deactivate pending orders by referencing
their names, which were generated by the functions: strategy.order,
strategy.entry and strategy.exit.

